# Call a getFullYear() on a date after retrieving it from localStorage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

```js
const formDepositsData = [];

      const [depositsData, setDepositsData] = 
      useState(formDepositsData);
 
    "localStorage"
      useEffect(() => {
        const deposits = 
     JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deposits"));
        if (deposits) {
          setDepositsData(deposits);
        }
      }, []);

      useEffect(() => {
           localStorage.setItem("deposits", 
           JSON.stringify(depositsData));
           }, [depositsData]);
```

I want to be able call a getFullYear() on a date after retrieving it from localStorage but as we know before we can use local storage we have to stringify so it returns only a string and on a string we can't call getFullYear()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where's your date but you can *stringify* a date:

```js
const d = new Date()
localStorage.setItem('date', d.toISOString()) // converts date to iso string
const d2 = new Date(localStorage.getItem('date')) // create date from string
d2.getFullYear()
```

Comment: its in an array of objects so i have to loop over the array and change it all over and then get it back but the problem is that if its crashing when i open it because in the beginning it does not return a date format so before getting the array it should already be changed to a date

Comment: {name: "try it", date: "2022-07-14T00:00:00.000Z", depositAmount: "11", balanceAmount: "16",…}